# The gdb in my machine does NOT support tui display

Tags: gdb

I have a question, when I'm using riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb to debug my code, when I fire the command:

```
~/xv6-labs-2020# riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb -tui kernel/kernel
riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb: TUI mode is not supported
```

It seems like not a lot people encounter this problem, but this really stops me, I need the layout to check the instructions running, but it does NOT support, so any solution to it?? thx!

Answer (score 0):

This means that your gdb was built without the TUI.  The only way to fix it is to rebuild gdb, using the `--enable-tui` flag to `configure`, and making sure that the needed libraries (curses primarily) are available.

Comment: I just install all the toolchain from `https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.S081/2020/tools.html``, for me ,it 's too hard to rebuild just one component...

Answer (score 0):

you nee add curses support
possible solution in Ubuntu

```
sudo apt install libncurses5-dev -y
```

then remake toolchain

```
sudo make clean
sudo make -j16
```

https://github.com/riscv-collab/riscv-binutils-gdb/issues/256